# Simple Age Verification in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a total Js noob and i'm trying to make a simple script to take values from two input tags and based on their value change a p tag. I'm probably just not using proper syntax but I can't find an answer online to how to do this.

The script is supposed to be like age verification for an r-rated movie. The first input is age and the second is whether or not the customer has an adult with them for if they are underage.

```
<pre>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <input type="text" id="age" value="your age">
    <input type="text" id="adult" value="(y or n)">
    <input type="button" onclick="checkAge()" value="submit">
<p id="answer"></p>
<script>
var age = document.getElementById("age").innerHTML;
var adult = document.getElementById("adult").innerHTML;
var result = document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML;
var oldEnough = false;
function checkAge(){
    if(age.value >= 18){
        oldEnough = true;
    }
    else{
        oldEnough = false;
    }
    if(oldEnough == false){
        if(adult.value == "y"){
            result = "You are not old enough, but have an adult with you.";
        }
        else{
            result = "You are not old enough and are unaccompanied."
        }
    }
    else{
        result = "You are old enough."
    }
}
</script>
</html>
</pre>
```

Comment: Reminder: Java != Javascript

Comment: If you need to put extra explanation, edit it into the question, not a comment.

Comment: You want to get the value from an input, not the innerHTML. So `document.getElementById("age").innerHTML` should be `document.getElementById("age").value` (same for the others). You also want to set those variable inside your function.

Comment: Processing is a lot easier if you put the input elements into a form.

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't call `.innerHTML` on the input elements. Just set the variables to point to the elements.
2. When assigning the result, you need to use `result.innerHTML` at the time of the assignment. Assigning `.innerHTML` to the variable just copies the current contents of the element as a string, it doesn't make `result` a reference to the `innerHTML` property.
3. You should call `parseInt` on `age`, because `.value` is a string.

```js
function checkAge() {
  var age = document.getElementById("age");
  var adult = document.getElementById("adult");
  var oldEnough = false;
  var result = document.getElementById("answer")
  if (parseInt(age.value, 10) >= 18) {
    oldEnough = true;
  } else {
    oldEnough = false;
  }
  if (oldEnough == false) {
    if (adult.value == "y") {
      result.innerHTML = "You are not old enough, but have an adult with you.";
    } else {
      result.innerHTML = "You are not old enough and are unaccompanied."
    }
  } else {
    result.innerHTML = "You are old enough."
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="age" placeholder="your age">
<input type="text" id="adult" placeholder="(y or n)">
<input type="button" onclick="checkAge()" value="submit">
<p id="answer"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The input elements can be more easily accessed if they are put in a form, and the logic can be simpler. Also, make sure you use appropriate elements and attributes, e.g. don't use value as a kind of placeholder, it should be a suitable default value (if there is one).

And don't use placeholders instead of labels, they should only be used as a hint for the kind of content required, they don't replace labels.

```js
function checkAge(button) {
  var form = button.form;
  var result = document.getElementById("answer");

  result.innerHTML = form.age.value >= 18? 'You are old enough.' :
                     form.adult.checked? 'You are not old enough, but have an adult with you.' :
                     'You are not old enough and are unaccompanied.';
}
```

```html
<form>  
  <label>Age: <input type="text" name="age"></label>
  <label>Adult: <input type="checkbox" name="adult"></label>
  <input type="button" onclick="checkAge(this)" value="Check age">
  <p id="answer"></p>
</form>
```